# What is the etymology of the legal term "squatting" as in occupying unowned property?

Tags: etymology

Does it have connection to the physical act of squatting or is it coincidental? After all, people that occupy a property, may just lie or stand in there, instead of squatting. So this does not seem to be very logical.

I can't find any etymology or origin story of the legal term...

Comment: The OED gives first citation of 1788 for *squatter* and 1800 for *squat* (verb), and it seems to come from the USA, although the OED says it was also used in early Australia. But I can't find any etymology. You might guess it refers to the position of someone sitting on their haunches, but why they'd choose squatting rather than sitting, kneeling, or lying for the posture of someone enjoying the possession of land, I don't know. Maybe it's intended to be dismissive or ugly-sounding, or refers to the popularity of squatting among native peoples who don't have chairs.

Comment: This may help [link](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=squatter)

Comment: @StuartF I guess it's also worth to note that Russian "gopniks" (street gangsters) are strongly associated with squatting position. This kind of fits the image nicely.

Comment: As to sitting in a squat, in general, *to beset*, *sit on*, German *besetzen*, *ersitzen*, Latin *possess* (if from *sed*, though unlikely, it still sounds like German has calqued it), more properly *resident, preside over*, etc. are using a fairly natural metaphor of *taking place*, so there are bound to be more (not unlike Spanish *estar* "to be, stand"). There is no indication that Gopniks or their manners were involved, at all, or that *sit* is always etymologically correct.

Comment: Italian *scuderia* is probably the best fit for both *scoot* "to travel fast" and *squat* (if "settling beyond the official limits […]" is instructive). *esquire*, from *scutarius* "shield bearer", might be relevant if squatters *lawyered up*, which tends to be their best defensive mechanism now in an urban environment (the change of semantics seems to involve "protective").

Comment: @StuartF Maybe you squat because the floor is dirty and you have no furniture...

Comment: Cf. **squattle** v. "to settle down" in Joseph Wright, *English Dialect Dictionary* volume 5, R-S (Oxford, 1905).

Answer (score 2):

[Oxford reference.com](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100525881) explains how the term evolved and came to be used to mean, by extension, illegally occupy  a property.

> In the USA, from the late 18th century, a squatter was a settler having no normal or legal title to the land he occupied, particularly in a district not yet surveyed.
>
> In New South Wales, Australia, the term was applied from the early 19th century to those, often ex-convicts, who occupied land without authority and stole stock.
>
> By the 1830s, its meaning had begun to broaden, often being applied
> to the many pastoralists settling beyond the official 1829 limits of
> settlement. They were mostly involved in the wool industry, and in
> 1836 were granted grazing rights for an annual licence fee. The
> squatters demanded security of tenure and pre-emptive rights, which
> they gained in 1847, securing the land most suitable for agricultural
> and pastoral purposes. Thereafter squatters became a very powerful
> group, socially, economically, and politically; they often struggled
> bitterly over land with selectors during the second half of the 19th
> century. Squatters continued to be known by that name even after they
> acquired their land freehold. Eventually, the term was applied to all
> large pastoralists in Australia.
>
> Squatting nowadays generally results from housing shortages, but whereas in rich countries squatters tend surreptitiously to take single buildings, in poorer ones the illegal occupation of land is on so great a scale that the authorities often condone it and sometimes grant squatters legal title.

Comment: The answer may be missing the why of the core word *squat*, not the extension of meaning.

Comment: The question very clearly asked if the legal term relates to the anatomical meaning of *squatting*. I don't think that this replay answers the question. And I definitely don't think that an answer to this question *may be missing* the why of the core word *squat*.

Comment: You can only squat for so long... You can sit, lay, or stand for much longer. Squatting is necessarily more ephemeral.